# azure-devops-extension-api (sdk): APIs error when using in pipeline extension

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I'm building an Azure DevOps pipeline extension and want to use Data [Storage feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/data-storage?view=azure-devops#data-collections-of-documents-storage)

I'm using typescript for development and the following API:
 - [azure-devops-extension-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-devops-extension-api)
 - [azure-devops-extension-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-devops-extension-sdk)

I was able to write a function and it compiles without any issues:

```
const extensionId = SDK.getExtensionContext().extensionId;
const accessToken = await SDK.getAccessToken();
const dataService = await SDK.getService<IExtensionDataService>(CommonServiceIds.ExtensionDataService);
const manager = await dataService.getExtensionDataManager(extensionId, accessToken);
const document = await manager.getDocument('MyCollection', 'MyDocument');
document.action = 'hello world - pipeline';
manager.updateDocument('MyCollection', document).then(function (doc) {
  LoggingUtils.logMessage(`Doc version: ${doc.__etag}`);
});
```

The issue is that at runtime I'm getting an error: **Unhandled: define is not defined**

The issue has something to do with modules, but I can't get what can be wrong here. I tried to change the **module** parameter in **tsconfig** to **commonjs**, **amd**, **umd** which didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution of how to use a Data Storage inside pipelines extension application.

I've created a repository and example of its usage:
https://github.com/parkhomenko/azure-build-task/blob/master/nodeFiles/index.ts